# ASP.Net - Change CssClass Property of a Button Based on Logic Behind

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

I have a timer that ticks every 30 seconds and checks for records retrieved by a stored procedure. There are 3 options; either no results so don't show a button, there are results and at least one of them is an "emergency" so show the "emergency button", or there are results with no emergencies so show the "standard button."

I have two CSS classes that both work on their own but I can't seem to get the CssClass property of the asp:Button to change in my VB.Net code, any help? I've tried multiple things, below is a mock-version my most recent attempt.

```
If results.Count > 0 And blnEmergency = True Then
    btnTicketAlert.Attributes.Remove("CssClass")
    btnTicketAlert.Attributes.Add("CssClass", "EmergencyButton")
    btnTicketAlert.Visible = True
ElseIf results.Count > 0 And blnEmergency = False Then
    btnTicketAlert.Attributes.Remove("CssClass")
    btnTicketAlert.Attributes.Add("CssClass", "TicketButton")
    btnTicketAlert.Visible = True
Else
    btnTicketAlert.Visible = False
End If
```

I believe that IF this is indeed the way to do it, I am simply missing the part where the change is pushed back to the server. If that's the case I do not know what is needed to do that.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it should be used like this:

```
btnTicketAlert.CssClass = "TicketButton"
```

i.e.

```
If results.Count > 0 And blnEmergency = True Then
    btnTicketAlert.CssClass = "EmergencyButton"
    btnTicketAlert.Visible = True
ElseIf results.Count > 0 And blnEmergency = False Then
    btnTicketAlert.CssClass = "TicketButton"
    btnTicketAlert.Visible = True
Else
    btnTicketAlert.Visible = False
End If
```

*update:

```
btnTicketAlert.Attributes.Remove("CssClass")
btnTicketAlert.Attributes.Add("CssClass", "TicketButton")
```

doesn't work for me though.

```
btnTicketAlert.Attributes.Remove("class")
btnTicketAlert.Attributes.Add("class", "TicketButton")
```

works instead.

Anyways, you probably already checked but in case if there's no issue on your code behind the how about your placement of timer/button, (such in case you're using update panels)

Comment: Just got into work and tried switching "CssClass" to "Class" and it worked for me, not sure what I did wrong the first time because I swore i tried it. Nonetheless thanks for helping me out!